# Can I debug in Intellij Idea over @Around aspect

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, aspect

I have a couple of @After and @Before aspects, and debug is working just fine. But when I try with @Around, it just wont stop at the break point. I have logs, and I'm sure that aspect code is executed.

Is this normal, or is it just me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed, it was me! :)

I have several Around aspects and of course, on the top of every one, I need to define order. I put correct order on top of my new aspect, but missed to add new one to old aspects. Now I did it, and debug is alive! :)